# running vs2015 in docker image

Tags: visual-studio, docker, development-environment, docker-image

Is it possible to create a visual studio2015 docker image?

I need to have complete development environment in a docker image, so i can run this image to coding and publishing etc just like what we do already with vs installed on a normal windows. Machine or vm.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time thinking of a good reason for this... even if it was possible, which seems unlikely to me.

Comment: Agree with @JonStirling but absolutely:  Create a base image with VS installed.

Comment: @axlj Even if you could install it, could you run it? I've not seen docker run in a non-headless state, but maybe that's just because I've never needed it...?

Comment: The reason 1) i have a developer team that has their vm with vs2015 installed, every time a vs update released all of team members need at least a couple of hours installing update. Reason 2) i can just sent image to my graphists to work on design without needing to install vs on their computers 3) having multiple projects in old envs and we can create a needed image for each and use them without need to install many envs

Comment: @jonstirling you could remote desktop into it

Comment: @axlj Suppose that is true. Not that it doesn't sound horrible!

Comment: @mesut Distribute a VM HDD then? Why does this need docker?

Comment: You are asking about Application Virtualization, not Containers. AppV is part of Windows for quite some time

Comment: @mesut check out https://www.vagrantup.com/.  It allows for scripting of VMs for development purposes.  It might fit your need better.

Comment: @axj wron scenario. The OP isn't really asking about VMs. There is only an assumption that VMs or Docker can fix what is an update problem. Even with a VM - why not generate a new VHDX each time and distribute it? Customizations would probably be lost, but the same would happen with Docker. AppV though is made to handle just that

Comment: VHDX. And you can boot directly to a VHDX, not even start up a virtual machine. You should check what Windows already offers, because containers are *not* meant for such jobs

Comment: look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker

Comment: @user2915097 the OP isn't asking about deploying to Docker. He is asking about installing Visual Studio itself inside docker to impore update times. Which can't be done that way

Comment: Another reason is in vm i needs about 2gb and about 10gb hdd for just running windows 10 but i think if this would possible to run vs on docker i will need less resources for each developer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. There is a [Visual Studio blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/09/18/installing-build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-in-a-docker-container/) showing how to do this. While the instructions are for VS 2017, you should be able to substitute the VS 2015 command-line installer.

Note that there is a caveat in the blog page about VS 2015:

> Installing Visual Studio 2013, 2015, or 2017 on microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1593 (which may be your locally cached :latest depending on when you last pulled) fails. The bootstrapper fails to launch the installer. Please use either an older tagged build like :10.0.14393.1480 or newer tagged build like :10.0.14393.1715 – the current :latest when this post was first published.

Answer (score -4):

Not yet! Docker depends on the sharing of an linux kernel.
If you know to install VS2015 in Linux, you can install it in docker too.

Comment: as I know windows container is on the way in windows server 2016 isn't it help me?